# Check InDesign Links for missing XMP - DocumentID and InstanceID

Tags: adobe, metadata, adobe-indesign, extendscript, xmp

I am using ExtendScript to work on metadata information of `.indd` files in  InDesignCC 2019.

My requirement is that I need to access all individual links metadata associated with the `.indd` file and see whether any of the links metadata is missing `DocumentID` and `InstanceID`. If any of the links metadata do not have a value for `DocumentID` and/or `InstanceID` properties then I need to display the file name associated with that link, indicating that, that particular file is missing a `DocumentID` and/or `InstanceID`.

I have used the below script to access the meta data of `.indd` file.

```js
$.level=0

// load XMP Library
function loadXMPLibrary() {
    if (!ExternalObject.AdobeXMPScript) {
        try{ExternalObject.AdobeXMPScript = new ExternalObject('lib:AdobeXMPScript');}
        catch (e){alert('Unable to load the AdobeXMPScript library!'); return false;}
    }
    return true;
}

var myFile= app.activeDocument.fullName;
 var myXmp = null;

// check library and file
if (loadXMPLibrary() && myFile !== null) {
    xmpFile = new XMPFile(myFile.fsName, XMPConst.FILE_INDESIGN, XMPConst.OPEN_FOR_UPDATE);
    myXmp = xmpFile.getXMP();
     $.writeln(xmpFile.getPacketInfo());
}


if (myXmp){
      $.writeln (myXmp);
    $.writeln (XMPFile.getFormatInfo(XMPConst.FILE_INDESIGN));

}
```

Can any one  help me how can I proceed further in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've obtained the XMP from the link, i.e. `xmpFile.getXMP()`, you'll need to:

1. Utilize the [`getProperty()`](https://javascript-tools-guide.readthedocs.io/scripting-xmp/xmpscript-object-reference.html?highlight=setProperty()#getproperty) method to retrieve the value of a specific metadata property.
2. Typically the `DocumentID` and `InstanceID` will be associated with the [`NS_XMP_MM`](https://javascript-tools-guide.readthedocs.io/scripting-xmp/xmpscript-object-reference.html?highlight=setProperty()#schema-namespace-string-constants) schema namespace, which is described as:

   > **`NS_XMP_MM`**   The XML namespace for the XMP digital asset management schema.

   For instance, to obtain the `DocumentID` you'll do something like the following:

   ```js
    var documentID = allXMP.getProperty(XMPConst.NS_XMP_MM, 'DocumentID', XMPConst.STRING);
   ```

---

#### Solution:

The gist below (*example.jsx*) performs the following:

1. Checks whether a `.indd` file is open and notifies the user if there is not one open.
2. Loads the AdobeXMPScript XMP Library
3. Checks that the status of all Links are *"OK"*, i.e. it checks that they are not *"Modified"*, nor *"Missing"*. If any link status is not *"OK"* the user is asked to update their status to *"OK"*.
4. Checks whether each linked asset has a `DocumentID` and `InstanceID` and logs their values to the *JavaScript Console*.
5. For any linked asset that does not have a `DocumentID` and/or `InstanceID` an alert dialog appears indicating the name and path to the linked asset.

**example.jsx**

```js
$.level=0;

// Warn if there are no documents open.
if (!app.documents.length) {
  alert('Open a document and try again.', 'Missing Document', false);
  exit();
}

var doc = app.activeDocument;

// load XMP Library
function loadXMPLibrary() {
  if (!ExternalObject.AdobeXMPScript) {
    try {
      ExternalObject.AdobeXMPScript = new ExternalObject('lib:AdobeXMPScript');
    } catch (e) {
      alert('Failed loading AdobeXMPScript library\n' + e.message, 'Error', true);
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

// Check all link statuses are be ok.
function linksStatusCheck(doc) {
  for (var i = 0, len = doc.links.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (doc.links[i].status !== LinkStatus.NORMAL) {
      alert('The status of all links must be OK \nPlease update link status ' +
          'via the Links panel and try again', 'Link Status', true); 
      exit();
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function checkLinksXMP(doc) {
  for (var i = 0, len = doc.links.length; i < len; i++) {

    var linkFilepath = File(doc.links[i].filePath).fsName;
    var linkFileName = doc.links[i].name;

    var xmpFile = new XMPFile(linkFilepath, XMPConst.FILE_INDESIGN, XMPConst.OPEN_FOR_READ);
    var allXMP = xmpFile.getXMP();

    // Retrieve values from external links XMP.
    var documentID = allXMP.getProperty(XMPConst.NS_XMP_MM, 'DocumentID', XMPConst.STRING);
    var instanceID = allXMP.getProperty(XMPConst.NS_XMP_MM, 'InstanceID', XMPConst.STRING);
      
    // Useful for testing purposes....
    // Log properties for each link to the console.
    $.writeln('linkName: ' + linkFileName);
    $.writeln('filePath: ' + linkFilepath);
    $.writeln('DocumentID: ' + documentID);
    $.writeln('InstanceID: ' + instanceID);
    $.writeln('-------------------------------------');

    // Notify user when XMP is missing...
    if (!documentID && !instanceID) {
      alert('Link missing DocumentID and InstanceID\n' + 
          'Name: ' + linkFileName + '\n\n' +
          'Path: ' + linkFilepath, 'Missing XMP', true); 
    } else if (!documentID) {
      alert('Link missing DocumentID\n' + 
          'Name: ' + linkFileName + '\n\n' +
          'Path: ' + linkFilepath, 'Missing XMP', true); 
    } else if (!instanceID) {
      alert('Link missing InstanceID\n' + 
          'Name: ' + linkFileName + '\n\n' +
          'Path: ' + linkFilepath, 'Missing XMP', true);
    }
  }
}

if (loadXMPLibrary() && linksStatusCheck(doc)) {
  checkLinksXMP(doc);
}
```